# How do i make sure my partition is mounted automatically?

Tags: centos, fstab

How do i make sure my sdb1 partition is mounted automatically each time i reboot, or is the current configuration correct, is there anything i need to change? I am using CENTOS6.8 as a virtual machine in Vmware. Thank You.

```
UUID=0d5c8e6d-4fc7-9390-e2ecac6fe2f /boot           ext4      defaults   1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the details into /etc/fstab (see the man page) will ensure it gets mounted on boot.

Comment: Could you show me an example of that. thank you. I can see the "see man pages fstab(5)" in the /etc/fstab file

Comment: The line i posted in my question is already within the fstab file. i typed cd /etc then vi fstab and that line was already present in that file. Ive rebooted the vm and i did a ls /dev/sd* command and sdb1 is still present.